# Multidimensional Array key value of one array into another array in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays.

First array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17, karol Bagh
        [1] => Noida
        [2] => Delhi
        [3] => India
        [4] => 426001
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 117, Srinagar
        [1] => Gaziabad
        [2] => Delhi
        [3] => India
        [4] => 426001
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 109,Bangalore
        [1] => Bangalore
        [2] => Karnataka
        [3] => India
        [4] => 560058
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Jeevan Shree Building, Ground Floor,S.No.1109, Ganeshkhind Road, Shivajinagar, Near Pune Central
        [1] => Pune
        [2] => Maharashtra
        [3] => India
        [4] => 411005
    )

)
```

Second array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [LatitudeLongitude] => 28.6192015, 77.2791726
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [LatitudeLongitude] => 28.5615316, 77.268723
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [LatitudeLongitude] => 13.0525001, 77.4869828
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [LatitudeLongitude] => 18.5204303, 73.8567437
    )

)
```

**I need an array like by combination of this two array in php :**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17, karol Bagh
        [1] => Noida
        [2] => Delhi
        [3] => India
        [4] => 426001
        **[5] => 28.6192015, 77.2791726**
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 117, Srinagar
        [1] => Gaziabad
        [2] => Delhi
        [3] => India
        [4] => 426001
        **[5] => 28.5615316, 77.268723**
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 109,Bangalore
        [1] => Bangalore
        [2] => Karnataka
        [3] => India
        [4] => 560058
        **[5] => 13.0525001, 77.4869828**
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Jeevan Shree Building, Ground Floor,S.No.1109, Ganeshkhind Road, Shivajinagar, Near Pune Central
        [1] => Pune
        [2] => Maharashtra
        [3] => India
        [4] => 411005
        **[5] => 18.5204303, 73.8567437**
    )

)
```

How to do this?

Comment: I have done this by : 
$index = 0;
for($index=0; $index<$id;$index++){
$propertyList[$index]['latitutelongitute'] =  $latlongarray[$index];
}

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $a) {
    $array1[$key][] = $array2[$key]['LatitudeLongitude'];
}
```

This way you will iterate over the entire first array, getting the `LatittudeLongitude` index from the right key in the second array.

Hope I was helpful

Answer (score -1):

```
$index = 0;

foreach ($array2 as $entry) {
    array_push($array1[$index], $entry['LatitudeLongitude']);
    $index++;
}
```

This snippet loops through the 2nd array, in which you're holding lat/lng data. We are taking the ['LatitudeLongitude'] field of each entry in the 2nd array, and pushing it into the nested array that exists at the same index in the first array. The incremented variable acts as a reference to our position in both arrays.

So always we have `$2ndarray[0]['LatitudeLongitude'] -> $1starray[0]`, `$2ndarray[1]['LatitudeLongitude'] -> $1starray[1]`, .... and so on (where `$1starray[$i]` is an array itself).